# Cannot initialize a new MySQL-8 data directory

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I recently upgraded to a new Windows PC and for various reasons relating to stupidity find myself with a Laragon installation that will not initialize a MySQL data directory correctly.  I am using MSQL8. When running the initialize command I get various error related to syncing auto.cnf or binlog.index in the data directory.

The basic error message is:
mysqld: Can't sync file 'M:\laragon\data\mysql-8\auto.cnf' to disk (OS errno 22 - Invalid argument [OS Error Code : 0x1e3])
2023-12-24T04:35:43.475757Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010076] [Server] Initialization of the server's UUID failed because it could not be read from the auto.cnf file. If this is a new server, the initialization failed because it was not possible to generate a new UUID.

The auto.cnf file does contain a UUID in form: server-uuid=e61ff650-...

So far, I have tried two different versions of MySQL8, mysql-8.0.30-winx64 and mysql-8.0.30-winx64 both with the same results.  I have tried the my.ini as it came in Laragon and one reduced to the bare minimum based on advice seen elsewhere. Each test has begun with a clean data directory.

My.ini

```
[client]
#password=your_password
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=512M
table_open_cache=256
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_cache_size=8

#secure-file-priv=""
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
basedir="M:/laragon/bin/mysql/mysql-8.0.35-winx64"
datadir= "M:/laragon/data/mysql-8"
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

My current efforts have been from the command line with the following result.  All of the Laragon related directories including the data directory are in the Path environment variable.

```
------> mysqld --initialize-insecure --console
2023-12-24T04:35:43.384530Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] M:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.35-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.35) initializing of server in progress as process 29828
mysqld: Can't sync file 'M:\laragon\data\mysql-8\auto.cnf' to disk (OS errno 22 - Invalid argument [OS Error Code : 0x1e3])
2023-12-24T04:35:43.475757Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010076] [Server] Initialization of the server's UUID failed because it could not be read from the auto.cnf file. If this is a new server, the initialization failed because it was not possible to generate a new UUID.
2023-12-24T04:35:43.475814Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013455] [Server] The newly created data directory M:\laragon\data\mysql-8\ by --initialize is unusable. You can remove it.
2023-12-24T04:35:43.475880Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-12-24T04:35:43.475989Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] M:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.35-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I am not an experienced Mysql configurator and rely of tools like Laragon to help get on with the job.  I can usually figure things out but this one has me stumped.  I have no idea where the invalid argument is.

Comment: After much fiddling I have it working again.  I believe the reason it was not working is MySQL's change to 'default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password' as the default authentication method and Laragons insistence on 'mysql_native_password'.  I tried to find where it Laragon is forcing the use of 'mysql_native_password' but could not find it anywhere.  To resolve this I have done a clean installation of Laragon and will deal with upgrading the authentication plugin at a later date.  Reloaded ad back up and am off and running ad least with the db.